# Lighttpd Authentication

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I have a Linux server in which I have installed Lighttpd (1.4.28). Now I have setup authentication for multiple folders (13) like this:

```
auth.debug = 2
auth.backend = "plain"
auth.backend.plain.userfile = "/home/.lighttpdpasswd"
auth.require = (

"/test1" =>
            (
            "method" => "basic",
            "realm" => "Password protected area",
            "require" => "user=test1"
            ),
.
.
.

"/test13" =>
            (
            "method" => "basic",
            "realm" => "Password protected area",
            "require" => "user=test13"
            ),
)
```

And the lighttpdpasswd is like this:

```
test1:test1
test2:test2
test3:test3
test4:test4
test5:test5
test6:test6
test7:test7
test8:test8
test9:test9
test10:test10
test11:test11
test12:test12
test13:test13
```

Now, for folders from 1 to 9, authentication works great, for 10,11,..13 the access is refused with correct credentials !

Is this a bug of lighttpd or should I add some parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

lighttpd mod_auth does a simple prefix match as it walks the auth.require list.  It does not look for complete path match, just prefix match.

A workaround is to place your longer paths before your shorter paths in the auth.require list, so "test10" and "test11" prior to "test1"

Comment: (having stumbled across this after a long time has passed ...)  lighttpd 1.4.70 adds warning trace at lighttpd startup if a longer path will not match due to a shorter path matching first.